# Docker Postgres PGAdmin4 MacOS - pgadmin4 does not show docker Postgres volume data after restart

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

I recently had to restart my machine, thus shut down my docker container and server connections. After restart PGAdmin4 no longer shows docker volume data, however my application is still able to access the docker volume data. I'm able to log in to my db as user postgres, though no tables show in the db. PGAdmin4 on 5050:5050, Postgres on 5432:5432, app on 5000:5000. I'm able to log into the db via PGAdmin while the container is paused, which wasn't the case before, finding it hard to understand why.

I've got a docker-compose file like so:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    image: postgres:12.2
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    volumes:
      - flask-app-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - pgnetwork

  pgadmin4:
    container_name: pgadmin4
    restart: always
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
      - SERVER_PORT=${SERVER_PORT}
    volumes:
      - pga4:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - 5050:5050
    networks:
      - pgnetwork

  dplio:
    container_name: dplio
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      # MY_ENV_VARS
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - .:/dplio
    networks:
      - pgnetwork
    depends_on:
      - postgres

networks:
  pgnetwork:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  flask-app-db:
    name: flask-app-db
  pga4:
    name: pga4
```

My terminal output when the containers are run:

```
Starting postgres ... done
Starting pgadmin4 ... done
Starting dplio    ... done
Attaching to pgadmin4, postgres, dplio
postgres    | 
postgres    | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres    | 
postgres    | 2020-03-17 11:18:55.599 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Debian 12.2-2.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
postgres    | 2020-03-17 11:18:55.599 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres    | 2020-03-17 11:18:55.600 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres    | 2020-03-17 11:18:55.604 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres    | 2020-03-17 11:18:55.619 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-03-17 10:41:43 UTC
postgres    | 2020-03-17 11:18:55.623 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
pgadmin4    | [2020-03-17 11:18:56 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
pgadmin4    | [2020-03-17 11:18:56 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:80 (1)
pgadmin4    | [2020-03-17 11:18:56 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: threads
pgadmin4    | [2020-03-17 11:18:56 +0000] [80] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 80
dplio       |  * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
dplio       |  * Environment: docker
dplio       |  * Debug mode: on
dplio       |  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
dplio       |  * Restarting with stat
dplio       |  * Debugger is active!
dplio       |  * Debugger PIN: 209-285-043
```

I thought to try a pg_restore from the docker volume to host but that doesn't seem to make sense as a potential solution, I think it's a connection issue between the docker container and my host machine, not a data loss problem.

I set PGAdmin4 port to 5050 in the browser, though it worked fine without that before I restarted.

I tried visiting http://localhost:5050/?key=xxxxxxx http://0.0.0.0:5050/?key=xxxxxxx and http://1270.0.0.1:5050/?key=xxxxxxx, the key taken from ~/.pgAdmin4.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.addr same issue.

I've tried removing my docker app image and rebuilding it, too.

Can anyone let me know what I'm missing? A step by step for shutting down server/container/network connections and restarting would be super helpful!

If you need more info let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: After several more problems, including my postgres user password not being recognised, I took the following steps to restore my environment: 1) `sudo pkill -u postgres` 2) `docker system prune -a --volumes` 3) `brew uninstall postgres` 4) `brew install postgres` following instructions from [ibraheem4](https://gist.github.com/ibraheem4/ce5ccd3e4d7a65589ce84f2a3b7c23a3) 5) `docker-compose up` 6) connect to pgAdmin with credentials as before - these steps resolved my connection problem, I didn't back my db as pw no longer worked, thus lost my data - not an ideal solution by any measure.

Comment: ^ _still keen to see a better solution if there's one out there!_